# Laravel Tumblr OAuth - Failed to Request Resource

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, tumblr

I'm getting the following error:

[image: Screenshot of the error]

I'm using artdarek's [oauth-4-laravel](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) but there doesn't seem to be much support in the Issues area.

My code is as follows:

```
public function tumblrLogin()
{
    $oauth_token = Input::get( 'oauth_token' );
    $oauth_verifier = Input::get( 'oauth_verifier' );
    $tumblr = OAuth::consumer('Tumblr', 'http://30daychallenges.net/auth/tumblr/');

    if ( !empty( $oauth_token ) && !empty( $oauth_verifier ) ) 
    {
        $token = $tumblr->retrieveAccessToken('Tumblr');
        $tumblr->requestAccessToken( $oauth_token, $oauth_verifier, $token->getRequestTokenSecret() );

        $result = json_decode( $tumblr->request('user/info'), true );

        dd($result);

    }
    else 
    {
        // get request token
        $token = $tumblr->requestRequestToken();
        // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
        $url = $tumblr->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $token->getRequestToken()));

        return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
    }
}
```

The error looks like it's coming from

```
$token = $tumblr->requestRequestToken();
```

But I can't see why - anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: A couple thoughts: Did you update the package config with your `Tumblr` `client_id` and `client_secret`?  What does `var_export(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));` show?  Does it work if you set a user agent (`ini_set('user_agent', 'oauth');`)?  Also, you might try debugging right at the error: `vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php`. Replace `error_reporting(0)` with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see if `file_get_contents` will throw any errors.

Comment: @patricus 

The var_export results in 1, so allow_url_fopen is working - as I have Facebook, Twitter and Google OAuth systems working also.

The ini_set doesn't fix it. I'm going to try directly debugging the file in question now - thanks!

Comment: @patricus The file_get_contents throws this:

`file_get_contents(https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my. I feel like such an idiot.

In `/app/config/packages/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel/config.php` I had the credentials in the array, however the array keys were consumer_key and consumer_secret, as Tumblr's API had suggested.

The oauth-4-laravel package expects these to be client_id and client_secret uniformly, so this is my bad.